# conda-build complains incorrectly that dependency is not included in meta.yaml

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am trying to build a Python module (`wsamdata`) as a conda package. `conda-build` fails with the error message (full output: https://pastebin.com/sKXNEcB6)

```
RuntimeError: Setuptools downloading is disabled in conda build.
Be sure to add all dependencies in the meta.yaml  url=https://pypi.org/simple/click/
```

`click` is a dependency, and therefore I have included it in my `meta.yaml` (see following), so I am a bit confused to see this message.

```
package:
  name: wsamdata
  version: 0.6.0
source:
  git_rev: v0.6.0
  git_url: https://github.com/kinverarity1/wsamdata
requirements:
  build:
    - python
    - pip
    - setuptools
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - geopandas
    - sqlparse
    - click
    - cx_Oracle
    - pillow
    - sqlalchemy
    - python-sa-gwdata>=0.5.4
    - lasio
  run:
    - python
    - numpy
    - pandas
    - geopandas
    - sqlparse
    - click
    - cx_Oracle
    - pillow
    - sqlalchemy
    - python-sa-gwdata>=0.5.4
    - lasio
```

Obviously `click` is also included under `install_requires=[...]` in the `wsamdata` package's `setup.py` file:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="wsamdata",
    version="0.6.0",
    packages=["wsamdata"],
    install_requires=[
        "python-sa-gwdata>=0.5.4",
        "pandas",
        "geopandas",
        "sqlparse",
        "click",
        "cx_Oracle",
        "pillow",
        "numpy",
        "sqlalchemy",
        "lasio",
    ]
)
```

I cannot share the source for `wsamdata`, so I understand this is not a reproducible example, but I am stuck and am wondering if I am missing something obvious. I've been able to successfully use `conda-build` on this machine to build a conda package for `python-sa-gwdata`.

I have found other similar questions, but they related to `conda skeleton` setups which produced `meta.yaml` files with missing requirements. I have instead written this `meta.yaml` from scratch.

My `.condarc` file:

```
channels:
  - kinverarity
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
ssl_verify: true
auto_update_conda: true
always_yes: true
show_channel_urls: true
create_default_packages:
  - pip
  - black
pip_interop_enabled: true
anaconda_upload: false
```

Comment: Experiencing the same issue for `pygithub` in my `meta.yaml`.  Spent 30 minutes trying to understand cause -- will search further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I had the same problem and resolved it using

`--single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt`

options at the pip install command, as suggested in the [anaconda cloud documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/resources/define-metadata.html#script)

If you are using `build.sh` or `bld.bat`, try:

```sh
$PYTHON setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt
```

or

```
"%PYTHON%" setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt
```

, respectively.

Alternatively, you can add this to your meta.yaml:

```yaml
build:
  script: {{ PYTHON }} setup.py install --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt
```

or, if you are using [conda skeleton](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda-build/en/latest/user-guide/tutorials/build-pkgs-skeleton.html), for packages already exist in pypi.org:

```yaml
build:
  script: {{ PYTHON }} -m pip install . --single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt --no-deps --ignore-installed --no-cache-dir -vvv
```

Comment: `pip` doesn't have these options:  `--single-version-externally-managed --record=record.txt ` - these are `python setup.py install` options.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well and it was rooted in conflicting version information in the `setup.py`/`requirements.txt` files compared to the `meta.yaml` files.  Look there and make sure any version specs are identical.  I was guided to this thanks to the ML post here:

https://groups.google.com/a/continuum.io/forum/#!msg/anaconda/dELRaivwdMg/5IWgDcdqAwAJ